NASM error: Invalid combination of opcode and operands on lines 17 and 22
I understand what the error means but I'm not sure what is the issue with my code. The errorous lines are 17 & 22
Line 17:
cmp [i], [esp]

Line 22:
mul ebx, i

i is a bss variable defined above with resb. From what I understand i becomes a byte pointer so line 22 should read mul ebx, [i] but that throws the same error, as for line 17 I have no idea what the problem could be. Full code is as follows:
extern dprintf
extern newline
extern space

section .bss
i resb 1

section .text
global _start
_start:
    ; Set i to 0, it will be incremented to 1 later
    mov byte [i], 0

.loop_start:
    ; If out of args, exit
    inc byte [i]
    cmp [i], [esp]
    jz .loop_end

    ; Print next arg
    mov ebx, 4
    mul ebx, i
    add ebx, 4
    add ebx, esp
    mov ebx, [ebx]
    call dprintf

    ; Print a space
    mov ebx, space
    call dprintf

    ; Continue
    jmp .loop_start
.loop_end:
    ; Print newline
    mov ebx, newline
    call dprintf

    ; Exit with exit code 0
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80

Other functions are defined in a another file which should be linked by ld, the relevant lines are as follows:
global dprintf
global newline
global space

section .data
newline db 0xa, 0x0
space db 0x20, 0x0

section .text
; Gets the length of the char* in ecx and puts it in edx
strlen:
    mov edx, ecx
    dec edx
.loop:
    inc edx
    cmp byte [edx], 0
    jnz .loop

    sub edx, ecx
    ret

; Like printf but will not save the values of eax and edx
dprintf:
    mov eax, 4
    call strlen
    int 0x80
    ret

